# Json data from table in an onclick function show in seperate div

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to get data used in my table to be used in a div when I click on the table. The thing is, there are multiple tables in my script according to the data of my JSON. So my JSON consists of object that consists of object. For example:
My table(s) are rendered like this:

```
data.forEach(function(somedata){

return '<table><tr><td>'+somedata.something+'</td></tr></table>';

});
```

Now I've tried to get the onclick to work in this case but I cant seem to figure out how. I'd like to not use specific ID's rendered in the foreach like:

```
var i=0;
data.forEach(function(somedata){
i++;
return '<table id="'.id.'"><tr><td>'+somedata.something+'</td></tr></table>';

});
```

**the variable somedata consists of an object so I cant just make an onclick in the html code of the table either and send the data in it.**

So `somedata` would look something like this but json encoded:

```
somedata{
[0]=>array(
    'something'=>'test',
    'theobject'=>array(...)
),
[1]=>array(etc...)

}
```

Now what I want is to get the data from `theobject` in a seperate div as soon as I click on the table that belongs to the right `somedata`.

I've been thinking of making a jquery on click for this but then I would need specific ID's in the table(if that's the only possible solution then I'd take it). Cant I do something with `this` or something? Or send the data at the same time it's being rendered cause in my code I can at the moment of course reach to  `somedata.theobject`

I think I'm thinking a bit too difficult about this. Am I?

Comment: Yes, you should use `$(this)` inside an event handler function to find out where the event occurred. And from that element you “navigate” to whatever related element you need to find - using methods like .parent, .parents, .siblings etc.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry I havent worked that much with `Jquery`. I have no clue how to achieve this with `$(this)`

Comment: Agree wih @CBroe additionally give `class` instead of `Id` and than bind click `$(".classname").on("click",function(){  $(this) // here you can find current table you clicked   });`

Comment: @Curiousdev That makes sense. Then I can just use the data like: `this.somedata.theobject`?

Comment: Yes that's right using `$(this)` you'll get a clicked `table` from DOM and than you can do other stuff whatever you wants

Comment: When I run that code instead of the `$(this)`  I run: `console.log('hello');` I get nothing. Am I missing something? I gave my table the same classname.

Comment: Ohh i have missed something you have dynamically generated table right your click event something like this `$("body").on("click",".classname",function(){ $(this) // here you can find current table you clicked });`

Comment: @Curiousdev I think I'm doing something wrong here. It's still not logging `hello`

Comment: can you please share your code how you are writing your click event? and one more thing make sure it'll in `document.ready` function and check your console is der any errors?

Comment: @Curiousdev nvm typo on my end it works. Thanks

Comment: @Curiousdev but now I still cant access `this.somedata` It gives me undefined. `this.data` gives me an empty line. `this` just gives me the html

Comment: @Curiousdev Keep in mind. I want to get `somedata.theobject` in my onclick function (which is not showing in the current table and shouldnt either)

Comment: what you need to do is to save that `somedata.theobject` in `table > tr` somewhere like `<tr class="someclass">somedata.theobject<tr>` and than onclick `$(this).find("someclass").text()` or `$(this).find("someclass").val()`  or `$(this).find("someclass").html()` this way you can find make this hidden if you don't want to visible anyone

Comment: @Curiousdev Is that the best way? Seems very sloppy. Also then I'd have to make a td with every single value in the object.

Comment: no that's not a best way though it'll work for u as a patch i would not recommended this way but as per your requirements dis is the only way i have in my mind for now

Comment: @Curiousdev thanks for being honest. I'll wait/research for a better solution

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go about this. Rather than using the `forEach` function we can use the `jQuery.map` function, since you've indicated that you're open to using jQuery :-)

```
var $els = $.map(data, function(somedata, i){
    var $el = $('<table><tr><td>'+somedata.something+'</td></tr></table>')
        .click(function(e) {
            populateDivWithData(somedata.theobject);
        });
    return $el;
});
```

The call to `.click` inside `each` will create a separate click handler for each item in data; each click handler then has access to the relevant `theobject` value.

EDIT: Thanks @Loko for the reminder about the `.forEach` built-in

Comment: `forEach()` Is a javascript function https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Where do you get the variable `i` from?

Comment: @Loko - the `jQuery.map` function provides the array index as a second parameter to the callback (as does the builtin forEach).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this in onclick function like

```
return '<table onclick=makeObject(this)><tr><td>'+somedata.something+'</td></tr></table>';
```

And then use the function to get the data

```
function makeObject(that){
    var tbl = $(that).find('tr').map(function() {
       return $(this).find('td').map(function() {
       return $(this).html();
      }).get();
    }).get();
}
```